# loading child swf as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I've been given an fla to make some changes too. Basically its a fairly long timeline animation with sound. So far I've successfully added a few button functions for sound etc.. but one has got me stumped.

One of the buttons needs to load a child swf. I'm using the code below but I'm recieving an error - 'Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference'. I believe this may be refferring to an object that isn't set yet but I have no idea which one it is:

Code:

```
var mcExt:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
var ldr:Loader = new Loader();
ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, swfLoaded);
ldr.load(new URLRequest("Downloads.swf"));

function swfLoaded(e:Event):void {
mcExt = MovieClip(ldr.contentLoaderInfo.content);
ldr.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, swfLoaded);
mcExt.x = 50;
mcExt.y = 50;
addChild(mcExt);
}
```

Any help on what is going wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: It looks like error is somewhere else. Try to figure out the line number by adding trace statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place

`ldr.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, swfLoaded);`

at the end of your code, making it:

```
var mcExt:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
var ldr:Loader = new Loader();
ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, swfLoaded);
ldr.load(new URLRequest("Downloads.swf"));

function swfLoaded(e:Event):void {
    mcExt = MovieClip(ldr.contentLoaderInfo.content);
    mcExt.x = 50;
    mcExt.y = 50;
    addChild(mcExt);
    ldr.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, swfLoaded);
}
```

I believe that the position of your `removeEventListener` is what is messing up your code.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than:

```
ldr.contentLoaderInfo.content
```

Try:

```
ldr.content
```

Hope that solves your problems!

Comment: afaict, both are valid and the same